# Python/Pandas: assign new column's value using information from one of three lists

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a new column in a pandas DataFrame. The new column called `"Region"` would indicate the region to which values from column `"City name"` belong to.

I have three lists corresponding to three different regions: North, Soud and West. Each region contains different country strings.

How can I do this? I found [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45184549/python-pandas-new-columns-value-if-the-item-is-in-the-list) but it only pertains to items belonging to one and only one list. In my case, items can belong to one of three lists.

Here's my attempt:

```
df["Region"] = pd.np.where(df["City name"].isin(N), "North", "")
df["Region"] = pd.np.where(df["City name"].isin(S), "South", "")
df["Region"] = pd.np.where(df["City name"].isin(W), "West", "")
```

My problem is that the second line override the first, and so forth with the third.

Comment: Probably want `np.select`  Can you post a small sample of your dataframe with a desired output?  However, you could also just replace the empty string with `df['Region']`, which would not override anything (but select is still better)

Comment: What is N, S, W? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Setup***

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'city name': ['Toronto', 'San Jose', 'Houston', 'Dallas']})
N = ['Toronto']
S = ['Houston', 'Dallas']
W = ['San Jose']
```

Using `np.select`:

```
c1 = df['city name'].isin(N)
c2 = df['city name'].isin(S)
c3 = df['city name'].isin(W)

df.assign(region=np.select([c1, c2, c3], ['North', 'South', 'West']))
```

Output:

```
  city name region
0   Toronto  North
1  San Jose   West
2   Houston  South
3    Dallas  South
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the data from user3483203

```
meltdf=pd.DataFrame({'North':N,'South':S,'West':W}).melt()
df.merge(meltdf,left_on='city',right_on='value',how='left')
Out[244]: 
     city variable   value
0  City A    North  City A
1  City B    South  City B
2  City C     West  City C
```

If the list is not all same length

change the `meltdf` to

```
meltdf=pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'North':N,'South':S,'West':W},'index').stack().reset_index()

df.merge(meltdf[['level_0',0]],left_on='city',right_on='level_0',how='left')
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you do not have too many outcomes, you can combine all three conditions:

```
df["Region"] = pd.np.where(df["City name"].isin(N), "North", 
                   pd.np.where(df["City name"].isin(S), "South", 
                       pd.np.where(df["City name"].isin(W), "West", np.nan)))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a `map` based solution?

```
mp = {k: lbl
      for lst, lbl in [(N, 'North'), (S, 'South'), (E, 'East'), (W, 'West')]
      for k in lst}

df['region'] = df['city name'].map(mp)

  city name region
0   Toronto  North
1  San Jose   West
2   Houston  South
3    Dallas  South
```

Map-based replacement is fast if you can setup the map with some minimal preprocessing.

(Data from @user3483203.)