# Insert a new column based on condition in each row

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataset that contains these values.

```
Game        
Cricket     
Football    
Basketball  
Snooker     
Bowling     
Baseball    
Cricket     
Football    
Basketball  
Snooker     
Bowling
```

I want to create a new column[Type] based on the values in the Game as below
Cricket, Football, Basketball should be classified as "Asia" while other games should be classified as "Europe.

```
Game         Type
Cricket      Asia
Football     Asia
Basketball   Asia
Snooker      Europe 
Bowling      Europe 
Baseball     Asia
Cricket      Asia
Football     Asia
Basketball   Asia
```

I always get the error "Value Error:- Length of values 14 does not match the index:- 2254

Comment: What is the condition? It's not clear how the mapping happens

Comment: create dict like `d = {'Cricket':'Asia', ..}` and then use `map`

Comment: Length of values (14) does not match the length of index (2295). I tried to use a dictionary and check but got the following error. I have been getting this error since... I believe I have to use some loop to fix this but not sure how.

Comment: @SteveKundukulangara - added new dupe for solution.

Comment: @jezrael I didn't quite get that? Can you elaborate please?

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45184549/python-pandas-new-columns-value-if-the-item-is-in-the-list) solution.

Comment: @jezrael. Thanks a lot sir. 5 days that's how many days I have been working on to get the solution. You are a true gem. really appreciate it.

Comment: @jezrael, does this work for multiple conditions? I have more than one condition and want to apply in it